# Creating script tool for definition query using user input

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters, definition-query

I have a map document with about 10 layers that I would like to create a query definition script tool to use that takes a user input as a parameter and then executes the tool. The script looks like this:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
field = 'Circuit'
#INPUT CIRCUIT USING THIS FORMAT: 'DC430'
value = 
queryStr = str(field) + "=" + str(value) 

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
        lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

I can't figure out how to configure the script tool to use the value variable as a user input that then gets used in the definition query. Is this possible?

Comment: Post your script toot configuration. I do not see your get/setparameterAsText in the script either. Check the documentation on creating script tools...

Comment: Another way to get some ideas on Get/SetParameterAsText() is by reviewing these Q&As: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-script-tool+parameters?sort=votes